# Выполнение функции в зависимости от числа переданных аргументов

Tags: python

Написал функцию:

```
import math

def my_range(*args):
    if len(args) == 3:
        start = args[0]
        stop = args[1]
        step = args[2]
    elif len(args) == 2:
        start = args[0]
        stop = args[1]
        step = 1
    elif len(args) == 1:
        start = 0
        stop = args[0]
        step = 1
    else:
        raise TypeError()
    k = start
    result = []
    while k < stop:
        result.append(k**2)
        k += step
    return result


print(my_range(2,8,2))
print(my_range(2,8))
print(my_range(4))
```

Можно ли как-то более красиво и элегантно выполнять функцию в зависимости от того, сколько в неё аргументов передано?

Comment: Можно, например вместо *args* принимать 3 параметра *start, stop, step,* но задать также им дефолтные значения. Т.е. ```def my_range(start=None, stop=None step=None) ```

Comment: @Nobody, в этом случае вызов из вопроса `my_range(2,8,2)` - отработает некорректно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно так:

```
def my_range(start=0, stop=None, step=None):
    if stop is None:
        stop = start
        start = 0
    step = step or 1
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, что элегантнее, но точно короче

```
def my_range(*args):
    if len(args) == 0:
        raise TypeError()

    start = args[0] if len(args) > 1 else 0
    stop = args[0] if len(args) == 1 else args[1]
    step = args[2] if len(args) > 2 else 1

    k = start
    result = []
    while k < stop:
        result.append(k**2)
        k += step
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Учитывая логику вашего кода, я вижу первоначальную ошибку с позиционированием аргумента **stop**. Стоит всего лишь **поменять местами stop/start** и **задать значения аргументов функции по умолчанию**, например:

```
def my_range(stop=1, start=0, step=1):
```

В этом случае **никаких условий и проверок не нужно вообще**, смотрите:

```
my_range(X, Y, Z) -> stop=X, start=Y, step=Z
my_range(X, Y) -> stop=X, start=Y, step=1
my_range(X) -> stop=X, start=0, step=1
```